# Windows system taskbar icons disappeared

Tags: windows, windows-8, taskbar, icons

Here is what they used to look like.
[image: System taskbar, Windows 8.1]

Now, the first five icons are missing -- the spaces are there, but no icons.  Right-clicking the spaces has no response, where before this would bring up a context menu for each associated application.

What's gone wrong?  How can I get back my icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution worked exactly as specified on this solution site:
[Instructions for resetting system taskbar icons...](http://ccm.net/faq/27246-windows-recover-lost-missing-system-tray-icons)

---

Reproduced below for permanence:

1. Go to Start > Run (or Windows-key + R), type in regedit and hit OK.
2. Navigate to the key:

   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\LocalSettings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\TrayNotify
3. Delete the values IconStreams and PastIconsStream.
4. Open up the Task Manager (Ctrl + Shift + Esc), go to the Processes tab, select explorer.exe and click End Process.
5. Open the Applications tab and click New Task at the bottom-right of the window.
6. In the message box that pops up type in explorer.exe and hit OK.
7. Explorer.exe will reload, and the missing icons should now be back in the system-tray where they belong.

Comment: Good Answer; just to avoid launching another explorer.exe process in step 6 type: %windir%\explorer.exe

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work. I still have missing icons for Edge and Settings.

Comment: @PeterX: if the icons were never on the task bar, then you can select them by right clicking a blank spot on the taskbar, selecting Taskbar settings... scrolling to Notification area, and clicking "Select which icons appear on the taskbar".